# Force deletion/disposing in C#

Tags: c#, dispose, delete-operator

This has never really occurred to me, because I never gave it much thought when I migrated to C# from C++, but... is there a way to force freeing of memory right there and then for something like `List`, array, or even objects that don't implement `IDisposable`?  Let me explain what's on my mind...

In C++, if I have want to create a dynamic array, I write something like this:

```
int* arr = NULL;
arr = new int[10];
```

...however, I have to delete it when I'm done, or there's going to be a memory leak:

```
delete [] arr;
```

Well, it doesn't seem like there's anything like that in C# or is there?  I haven't been able to find.  It appears that only objects that implement `IDisposable` interface can be forcefully disposed.  So, is setting say... array to `null` and letting GC clean up the only way to clean up memory in that case?

I've read up on `GC.Collect()` and that forcing earlier collection is frowned upon, so I was wondering if there's anything singular for these types?  I realize C# is not C++, I'm just curious to know if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: `IDisposable` have almost nothing to do with freeing memory... You can use some PInvoke (like `GlobalAloc`) to manage memory yourself, but that is probably not what you are looking for... Overall unclear what your goal of "force deletion" is - likely `GC.Collect` (2 standard lines `Collect`/`WaitForPendingFinalizers`) is what you looking for since there is no way to release memory used by single managed object.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Micromanaging of memory.  If I want to delete something when I need to delete it, I don't want to have to rely on GC.  This is not something that may be practical in every day use, but I'm curious to see if it can be done with this language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> setting say... array to `null` and letting GC clean up the only way to clean up memory in that case

well, the first bit is probably wrong, unless `arr` was actually (say) a field of another object that is going to continue to live for a long period of time. In your example, `arr` was a local variable, and the GC and JIT conspire (when you're running release code, not debug) to know the lifetime of such variables very accurately. They *know* that `arr` isn't used again and is so eligible for garbage collection - there's no need to assign `null` to it.

Now, to the broader question - no, there's no way to hand memory back eagerly. It would actually be *more* work to allow you to tell the GC "please take back this block of memory now"<sup>1</sup>. `GC.Collect`, as you say, is frowned upon, because even that isn't really "please take back this block of memory I'm no longer using", it's "please run your full analysis to determine *all* blocks of memory that are no longer required, then perform compaction, etc".

<sup>1</sup>The managed memory system has a trivial way of keeping track of available memory for new allocations - it's at the end of the block of all previous allocations. So compaction is the only way that released memory can be reused.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no existing way to free memory used by single managed object in .Net.

You can either

- manage native memory yourself (i.e. PInvoke for GlobalAloc functions)
- force complete garbage collection after releasing *all* non-weak references to particular managed object( `GC.Collect();GC.WaitForPendginFinalizers()`

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to PInvoke.  I'm exploring it right now.

Answer (score 0):

The classes of `IDisposable` interface implements method `Dispose`, which is the one for forcing object to be disposed.

But there is a Garbage Collector in C#, which automatically deletes all the object which are not referenced. It means that all local variables are deleted automatically when you leave its context, etc.

So in many cases, calling `Dispose` is not necessary ...

For general, if you want to free memory of object after its use, I recommend to use `using` statement:

```
using (... some object creation ...) 
{
    ... using object ...
}
// here, the object is disposed
```

Comment: Now I read it carefully and edited my answer to be answering right question, sorry for mistake. The part with Garbage Collector is that what could interest you ...

Comment: I still think it is answer for you. Ok, I will explain it more in next edit :-)

Comment: I'm aware of `using(){}`.

Comment: Ok, then I don't know what are you looking for - you know everything to reach your goal ...

Comment: Other answers says the same, that it is not possible to do it exactly same way as at C++ (like you want), but that there is another way how to do it.